# Running R scripts from UBUNTU fails due to packages installation

Tags: r, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vcf-vcard

I'm trying to run an R script from Ubuntu. the R script uses the vcfR library:

```
install.packages("vcfR")
library("vcfR")

vcf.rout<-"/mnt/c/Users/PC/Documents/aDNA/haplotypes.vcf"
vcf<-read.vcfR(vcf.rout)
```

When I run the script in R it works perfectly,
but when I run the script in Ubuntu, I get this error:

```
batelziv@DESKTOP-PGCKNUM:~$ Rscript /mnt/c/Users/PC/Documents/aDNA/Rs/unt1.R <br />
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’<br />
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)<br />
Warning in install.packages("vcfR") :<br />
'lib = "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"' is not writable<br />
Error in install.packages("vcfR") : unable to install packages<br />
Execution halted
```

I also tried running the script without the library related lines:

```
library("vcfR")

vcf.rout<-"/mnt/c/Users/PC/Documents/aDNA/haplotypes.vcf"
vcf<-read.vcfR(vcf.rout)
```

And I get:

```
    Error in library("vcfR") : there is no package called ‘vcfR’
    Execution halted
```

Why can't Ubuntu use the already installed packages? 
And why is it having trouble installing it?

Answer (score 1):

You have an error

> 'lib = "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"' is not writable

You are not authorized to write packages to this path.
I think when you install, you can add options `lib` with other paths or check if you can not write to it.

`install.packages(pkgs, lib = ...)`

Comment: usually the the path on Ubuntu systems is set to `~/R/...` in my case it is `~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0`, you can check that by calling `.libPaths()` in R.

Comment: @David `.libPaths()` returns `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library`. Because beginning installing progress message prints `Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’`. So I think he/she does not need to check it.

Comment: Thats true, `.libPaths()` prints the current paths where packages are installed to. I meant to say to check it just for better understanding of the internals, not necessarily to get the path for this particular use case. Maybe I should have clarified a bit more.